# FILTER for multiple conditions including OR

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

How can I use `FILTER` in a single formula to check for multiple conditions, such as in this case?

The filtered range must be `equals1` **AND** `notequal2` **AND** `equals3` **OR** `equals4`

This is of course an arbitrary scenario, I just wish to know the syntax of the logic operators.

Answer (score 1):

```
=FILTER(F:F, G:G="equals1",
             H:H<>"notequal2",
            (I:I="equals3") +
            (J:J="equals4"))
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer, but it could benefit from some explanation. What does `(I:I="equals3")+(J:J="equals4")` do - why the parenthesises and the `+`? Note that the OP asks _"I just wish to know the syntax of the logic operators."_

Answer (score 1):

It seems `FILTER` supports `*` and `+` as operators within `condition`s in the syntax `FILTER(range, condition1, [condition2, ...])` (AND between conditions is implied).
Thus, in your example you could use (I assumed you meant AND precedence over OR; other options can be easily handled)

```
FILTER(range, (range=equals1)*(range<>equal2)*(range=equals3)+(range=equals4))
```

Notes:

1. The use I have provided is the most versatile, as it allows for an arbitrary nesting and precedence of AND/OR operations.
2. In the "standard" syntax use there is no option for OR operations.
3. A "standard" syntax use    `FILTER(range, condition1, [condition2, ...])`
   can be replaced by     `FILTER(range, (condition1)*(condition2)*(...))`.